# React + Redux: How to wait for an action to complete and then redirect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am new to React but I've been working on Vue for many years. I am now stuck in one area when I need to wait for an action to complete. After the action is complete I have to make another action call or do some operations there. But it is not waiting for the action to complete and start executing the code below that.

Method:

```js
export const login = (email, password) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: USER_LOGIN_REQUEST,
    })

    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    }

    const { data } = await axios.post(
      '/users/login',
      { email, password },
      config
    )

    dispatch({
      type: USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    })

    localStorage.setItem('userInfo', JSON.stringify(data))
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: USER_LOGIN_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message,
    })
  }
}
```

Method from where action is dispatched :

```js
const redirect = location.search ? location.search.split('=')[1] : '/'

const submitHandler = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  dispatch(login(email, password))
  history.push(redirect)
}
```

Now, in the above code, the redirection is not waiting for the dispatch to complete. I tried this one but it is not working :

```js
const submitHandler = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  await dispatch(login(email, password))
  history.push(redirect)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume that when the below

```
dispatch({
      type: USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    })
```

happens that your `reduxState` has some sort of property like `isLoggedIn` or `isAuthenticated`. Now you can use the same property to trigger a `redirect` inside a `useEffect` like so :-

```
const {isAuthenticated} = reduxState;
useEffect(()=>{
if(isAuthenticated) history.push(redirect);
},[isAuthenticated])
```

and your `submitHandler` can be the following :-

```
const submitHandler = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  dispatch(login(email, password))
}
```

Comment: Thank you Lakshya. It really worked. I think I am still in the world of Vue. Just one question. Can we have multiple useEffect() in a component? Since I don't want one useEffect() to look for a change for all of my component data.

Comment: You can have multiple `useEffects`.

Comment: @LakshyaThakur I have a similar problem. I have the useEffect hook checking if the user is authenticated, but I want to show a toast when user is not authenticated and avoid navigation. How can I do that?